# Remove white space within a Text web-part in a modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-pages

A simple question - How do I remove the white space / blank line from between the text?

Much to my surprise, the options I see when editing the web-part don't allow me to do this.  Do I have to use CSS to do this?

[image: picture of a Text web-part on a modern page]

Comment: Did you use the "Heading 1", "Heading 2", etc. for this or "Normal text" with bigger font-size?

Comment: I've used Normal text and a bigger font-size.  It's a good suggestion to use the Heading options, as they do decrease white space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hitting Enter, hold down Shift and hit Enter. That way, the text is in the same paragraph and the spacing applied before and after a paragraph is not used.

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I didn't really want to switch to the other Heading 1, Heading 2 or Heading 3 options, as they change the way it looks, but this could be an option for others (this was Ganash' suggestion).

Answer (score 0):

Each new line in a Text web part uses the **<p>** tag. And <p> tag has the **margin-bottom:1.4em**. Due to that, we will get some blank space below the line.

To avoid it,

- Use the custom CSS
- Add the Ordered List or Unordered List element
- Have the content within a single paragraph.

Hope this helps.